# looking up in store from a component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a template that includes a component.

```
// pods/workgroup/template.hbs
...
{{workgroup/member-add
    wgId=model.id
    store=store
    peekUser2Workgroup=peekUser2Workgroup
}}
...
```

Within that component I need to lookup if something is already present in the store.

```
//somewhere in components/workgroup/member-add/componsent.js
let alreadyInStore = this.store.peekRecord('user2workgroup',u2wId);
```

I made it work by injecting the store into the component (as above), which of course is bad practise.
So I tried making a property in my parent-controller that does the store lookup:

```
//in components/workgroup/member-add/componsent.js
let alreadyInStore = this.get('controller').peekUser2Workgroup(u2wId);


//in pods/workgroup/controller.js
peekUser2Workgroup: function(u2wId) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.store);
    return this.store.peekRecord('user2workgroup',u2wId);
}
```

This works fine as long as I pass the complete store into the compentent as above.
However, if I *don't* pass the store to the component it get's undefined, although never accessed from the component directly (the store is present in the controller alone).

Logging into console of `this` gives me surprisingly the component, not the controller, `this.store` is undefined.
So I've learned, that with `this` I don't access the controller itself when a function/parameter gets called from outside/a component.

**The question is**, how can I make the controller to reference to itself with `this`?
Or how can I access the store when calling a parameter from outside?
Do I really need to pass the controller itself to himself??
like so:

```
// in component
let alreadyInStore = this.get('controller').peekUser2Workgroup(this.get('controller'), u2wgId);

//in controller
peekUser2Workgroup: function(myself, u2wId) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.store);
    return myself.store.peekRecord('user2workgroup',u2wId);
}
```

That seems very odd to me, and looks like I'm shifting around even more than I did initially when simply injecting the store to the controller...

Ember: 2.0.1
Ember-Data: 2.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing the store into the component as a property, inject it using Ember.service like this:

```
store: Ember.service.inject()
```

Then instead of passing in the function, just pass in the id vale you're looking up:

```
{{workgroup/member-add
    wgId=model.id
}}
```

Now in your component you can fetch the record:

```
workgroup: function(){
  return this.get('store').peekRecord('user2workgroup', this.get('wgId'));
}.property()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My point was, that I understood it to be bad practice to inject the store into a component - so I tried to avoid it. But it seems there's no way around...

Comment: Its not really a bad practice. Components were initially meant to be isolated, but people are learning that sometimes components need to be aware of their surroundings or pull in their own data.